# Column "columnName" does not belong to table "tableName"

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, connection-pooling

I have a .NET console application deployed to an Azure VM. The utility is pretty simple, it just looks at a table and sends emails. However, we randomly get errors on this line:

```
foreach (DataRow bcemail in BCEmails.Tables[0].Rows)
{
email.Subject = bcemail["subject"].ToString(); 
//other stuff
}
```

The error we received says: column 'subject' does not belong to table Table. I have checked that the stored proc always returns only 1 table and always has "subject" as a column. Keep in mind it works more than half the times, giving error only randomly. It works totally fine in my local environment. The Azure VM also has several other apps. Researching this problem, I found this link: 
http://www.ksvali.com/2010/08/solution-to-random-error-column-does-not-belong-to-table/
Which talks about corrupted database connection pool and recommends that you make sure the connection is closed properly. I have done this throughout the application. The link also mentions that we use 'iisreset' every time we stop the IIS server. So I tried doing an IISReset and running the app again and it works fine. If I do an IISReset every time before it's scheduled to run, it works fine.

My questions are this: 
1. This is a console app, not a web app, in fact there are no web sites configured on IIS on this VM. So why does IISReset work?
2. Can anyone recommend any other approach to solve this problem other than to do IISReset every time?

Comment: Are you opening and closing the connection explicitly, or are you using `Using...End Using` block for that?

Comment: we are using "using" block.

Comment: Have you added logging, and a test to see if the bcemail row has the column, and if not, log the table name and dump out the column collection? It seems a little debug logging might enlighten a bunch.

Comment: No I have not tried logging the column collection yet. However, I have used debugger to verify that the column is indeed returned in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after adding a new column to a table. The code was updated to reference the new column, but the stored prodcedures applicable were not updated. This error went away once the new column was added to the applicable stored procedures.